# Date Picker Input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, date

**How can I validate my HTML date input so only certain dates of the week can be selected?** I've seen this before on some booking websites. A date-picker calendar appears and days that the event is unavailable are grey out and cannot be selected.

I'm not sure where to start and I want to do this as my current project requires date input validation. The event is only available 3 days a week so it wouldn't make sense for the client to select a date when there is no event on.

Example, days are Monday, Wednesday and Friday so picking the Thursday 30th Nov shouldn't be an option.

**With the first-line question in mind, what would be the simplest programming language to create a date-picker on to go with a data driven website?**

Comment: You're going to want to use Javascript for this since it's client side, Look into the Date object, it has all the useful methods you'd need for validating things like day of the week. Good luck. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery date picker:

```
 <script>
        var disableDates = ["22-11-2017", "23-11-2017"];

        function disable(date) {
            // convert it to my formate
            dateToCheck = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
            if ($.inArray(dateToCheck , disableDates) == -1) {
                return [true, ""];
            } else {
                return [false, "", "disabled"];
            }
        }

        $(function() {
            $("#eventDate").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy',
                beforeShowDay: disable
            });

        });
    </script>
```